# Julia plots: replacing true tick values with counterfactual ones

Tags: plot, julia

Is there a way to overwrite/replace tick values in Julia's Plots package? For instance, consider a plot of function y=x where I want to (counterfactually) replace the xtick for x='1' to be displayed as x='100'.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
plot(1:10, sin.(1:10), 
    xformatter = xi -> string(Char(xi+64)),
    yformatter = yi -> yi==0 ? "zero" : "not zero")
```

[image: Plots.jl with custom ticks]